# Two separate lists of ints in from the same text file Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, readfile

I am having trouble trying to make two separate list of ints from the same text file.
Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
a = []
b = []
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    a.append(int(line[0].strip().split()))
    b.append(int(line[1].strip().split()))
```

input.txt file:

```
40 30 50 10
2 5 10 5
```

What I want:

```
a = [40,30,50,10]
b = [2,5,10,5]
```

Comment: 1) put `print(line)` into your code to see what `line` actually is 2) you have to call `split()` first before doing other operations, since the line is one long string which needs to be split into standalone numbers

Comment: post the error you encuountered to help us solve your problem

Comment: I would encounter this error:     p.append(int(line[0].strip().split()))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: below an answer by @SuperStormer was given and it fixed my list issue

Comment: sorry to had you bothered, was just going through the review queues and didn't realise there was already an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your lists of ints are all on the same line, so you don't need to loop over `f.readlines()`. Instead, split the first line, then map the strings to integers and repeat for the second list:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = list(map(int, f.readline().strip().split()))
    b = list(map(int, f.readline().strip().split()))
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mega = []
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    mega.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
```

This way you would get a list of lists which you can further separate according to your need:

```
mega = [[40,30,50,10], [2,5,10,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop by lines in your problem. Each line goes to a separate list.

```
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    a = list(map(int, infile.readline().split()))
    b = list(map(int, infile.readline().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
with open( 'input.txt' ) as fin :
    text = fin.readlines()

a = list( map( int, text[0].split() ))
b = list( map( int, text[1].split() ))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my way with very little hardcoding. Only creating the lists in your dictionary.

```
rowDict = {"a":[],"b":[]}
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for count,row in enumerate(f):
    rowDict[list(rowDict.keys())[count]].extend(list(map(int,row.strip().split())))
```

This would be my second example

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
a = list(map(int,f.readline().strip().split()))
b = list(map(int,f.readline().strip().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my version, kept the f.readlines and used extend instead of append to add the entire line mapped to int list to the empty lists:

```
a = []
b = []

f = open('input.txt', 'r')
line = f.readlines()
a.extend(map(int,(line[0].split())))
b.extend(map(int,(line[1].split())))
       
print(a)
print(b)
```